# Using dynamic search parameters with Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to follow the [Sequelize tutorial on their website](http://sequelizejs.com/).

I have reached the following line of code.

```
Project.findAll({where: ["id > ?", 25]}).success(function(projects) {
  // projects will be an array of Projects having a greater id than 25
})
```

If I tweak it slightly as follows

```
Project.findAll({where: ["title like '%awe%'"]}).success(function(projects) {
    for (var i=0; i<projects.length; i++) {
        console.log(projects[i].title + " " + projects[i].description);
    }
});
```

everything works fine. However when I try to make the search parameter dynamic as follows

```
Project.findAll({where: ["title like '%?%'", 'awe']}).success(function(projects) {
    for (var i=0; i<projects.length; i++) {
        console.log(projects[i].title + " " + projects[i].description);
    }
});
```

It no longer returns any results. How can I fix this?

Comment: I found the wording of your question a little confusing, so I edited it. I hope I understood correctly, please feel free to change it back if you think I screwed up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you would do that like this:

```
where: ["title like ?", '%' + 'awe' + '%']
```

So if you were doing this with an actual variable you'd use:

```
Project.findAll({where: ["title like ?", '%' + x + '%']}).success(function(projects) {
    for (var i=0; i<projects.length; i++) {
        console.log(projects[i].title + " " + projects[i].description);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 26):

Now on Sequelize you can try this

```
{ where: { columnName: { $like: '%awe%' } } }
```

See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators for updated syntax

Comment: Good simplistic answer. Quick note for new users, title is the name of the column you are wanting to find the match against.

Comment: Thanks @JMM I fixed it ;)

Answer (score 6):

Please try this code

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
{ where: { columnName: { [Op.like]: '%awe%' } } }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do it in this way:

```
Project.findAll({where: {title: {like: '%' + x + '%'}, id: {gt: 10}}).success(function(projects) {
  for (var i=0; i<projects.length; i++) {
    console.log(projects[i].title + " " + projects[i].description);
  }
});
```

In this way you can have nicely more WHERE clausas

Answer (score 0):

It might be cleaner to leverage the Sequelize.Utils.format function

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer of `["columnName like ?", '%' + x + '%']` for the where clause results in this error in Sequelize 4.41.1: "Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed."

Assuming: `modelName.findAll({ where : { columnName : { searchCriteria } } });`

Using `[Op.like]: '%awe%'` or `$like: '%awe%' }` as the searchCriteria (where 'awe' is the value you want to find in columnName) both result in SQL with a LIKE clause of `LIKE '\"%awe%\"'`. Notice the extra quotation marks. [Op.like] and $like are aliases of each other and neither answer the OP's question because they don't allow dynamic search parameters.

Using `` [Op.like] : `%${parameter}%` `` as the searchCriteria (where 'parameter' is the parameter whose value you want to find in columnName) resulted in SQL with a LIKE clause of `LIKE '\"%findMe\"'` when parameter= 'findMe'. Again, notice the extra quotation marks. No results.

An answer in [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935255/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-sequelize-query) suggested using `` [Op.like]: [`%${parameter}%`] `` for the searchCriteria (where 'parameter' is the parameter whose value you want to find in columnName). Notice the square brackets! This resulted in SQL with a LIKE clause of `LIKE '[\"%findMe%\"]'` when parameter= 'findMe'. Again notice the extra quotation marks and the square brackets. No results.

For me, the solution was to use a raw query:
`Sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName LIKE "%searchCriteria%"');`