# How to remove double quotes from Sequelize query?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm using Node/Express with Sequelize to query my sqlite database and when trying to query a column of type JSON, there are superfluous double-quotes (`"`) being added to the query which block the query from returning anything.

The code I'm using to make the query using Sequelize:

```
sites = await Site.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      'title', 'site_url', 'tags'
    ].map(key => ({
      [key]: {
        [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
      }
    }))
  }
});
```

The resulting (simplified) query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Sites` AS `Site` WHERE (`Site`.`title` LIKE '%min%'
  OR `Site`.`site_url` LIKE '%min%' OR `Site`.`tags` LIKE '"%min%"');
```

Notice the double-quotes: `` `Site`.`tags` LIKE '"%min%"' ``

When doing a manual query without the double-quotes, the query works as intended. So how can I remove them using Sequelize?

Comment: Are you sure you are not adding the double quotes in your application code

Comment: It's very possible. Although the column is of JSON type, the actual data I'm setting is an array. Would JavaScript add double quotes in there when making that conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure out a solution for this problem. Instead of:

```
[Op.like]: `%${search}%`
```

simply adding square brackets:

```
[Op.like]: [`%${search}%`]
```

made it so that Sequelize will search within the JSON while also searching other column types such as `varchar` like normal.