# Ptevent Sequelize wrapping column names in quotes

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, case-sensitive

I am using Sequelize with Postgres. I have db table and column names in pascal-case. In JavaScript I have everything in camel-case. Since Postgres is case-insensitive, it would not be a problem. However, Sequelize adds quotes to the names in queries, which makes Postgres case-sensitive. Is there a way to tell Sequelize to not wrap names in quotes?

Sequelize produces:  select "SalesItem"."Id" from "SalesItem" instead of select salesitem.id from salesitem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove double quotes from Sequelize query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935255/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-sequelize-query)

Answer (score 5):

In the [sequelize doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor), check out `options.quoteIdentifiers` seems like this might  solve your problem.  I haven't used this option (using mySql)

> options.quoteIdentifiers - Set to false to make table names and attributes case-insensitive on
>   Postgres and skip double quoting of them. WARNING: Setting this to
>   false may expose vulnerabilities and is not recommended!