# Stop Seqeulize wrapping columns with quotes

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize keeps wrapping the column identifiers with quotes what brakes the query right at the first column. I using `findAll` with no additional parameters which I assume selects all the columns. Here's the error:

> "SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7\ninvalid identifier '"id"'"

Query it attempted running

> SELECT "id", "organization_id" AS "organizationId", "account_locator" AS "accountLocator", "account_deployment" AS "accountDeployment", "audit_action" AS "auditAction", "reason", "reason_details" AS "reasonDetails", "executed_by" AS "executedBy", "executed_on" AS "executedOn" FROM "AUDITS"."ACCOUNT" AS "Audit" LIMIT 1;

[I have read about `options.quoteIdentifiers` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56583250/9559251) but it seems `6.27.0` of Sequelize no longer supports this.

Comment: Seems `options.quoteIdentifiers` is the main Sequelize instance option. `new Sequelize({ quoteIdentifiers: false })` does the job.

Comment: What DBMS do you use?