# Generate Sequelize LIKE query for JSON field

Tags: mysql, json, sequelize.js

I'm building a search query in Sequelize, querying a MySql database. I'd like to search for the same bit of text anywhere in several different fields, including JSON.  In the JSON I want to search for the text anywhere, not just on the values (as JSON_SEARCH would do). When I build this in Sequelize though, double quotes are being inserted for the JSON column only, causing the search to turn up nothing for that column. Here's a bit of the code (the actual code has several more columns):

```
const searchFilter = { [Op.like]: `%${value}%` };

const orFilter = [
  'name',
  'data',
].map((f) => Object.fromEntries([[f, searchFilter]]));

await Job.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: orFilter
  }
});
```

This generates the following Where clause:

```
WHERE (`job`.`name` LIKE '%text%' OR `job`.`data` LIKE '\"%text%\"');
```

`data` is a JSON field. Note the double quotes added to its LIKE clause. If I remove those quotes, the query works as expected. I suspect there's maybe something I can do with `literal` to prevent this, but I've tried a few variations and can't get it to work.

Note:
This question is *very* similar: [How to remove double quotes from Sequelize query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935255/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-sequelize-query). The answer didn't work for me, I believe because the OP's JSON was always an array. Here my JSON might be in any form.

Comment: Have you considered adding a [fulltext index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) to `(name, data)` and then search with MATCH...AGAINST?

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like it's not possible to add a fulltext index to a JSON column though: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html.

Comment: I tried changing the syntax in my answer below to use `sequelize.literal()` in the last parameter of `sequelize.where()` to add your quotes. Maybe it works, try it^^

Answer (score 1):

From the code I use for Postgres but adapted to MySQL, this should work:

```
await Job.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      sequelize.where(
        sequelize.col('name'), // Just 'name' also works if no joins
        Op.like,
        '%text%'
      ),
      sequelize.where(
        sequelize.col('data'), // Just 'data' also works if no joins
        Op.like,
        sequelize.literal('\"%text%\"')
      ),
    ]
  }
});
```

Explanation:

- `sequelize.where`: allows to create a Sequelize `where` value from an attribute, a comparator and a value.
- `sequelize.col`: does the escape with `'` marks for the text to be a valid column. **It is not necessary in your case, but I love it** because it works for joins : for example sequelize.col('Table1.Table2.field') works !

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't work as written though (Error: Invalid value { fn: 'JSON_EXTRACT' }). `sequelize.col('job')` doesn't make sense to me, as `job` is the table name. And doesn't `JSON_EXTRACT` need a path? I don't want a part of the json, I want to search the whole thing. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding and/or there's a small typo?

Comment: My bad, indeed I thought that "job" was also a column. I don't know it is is possible to search in all keys and all values of the JSON mh...

Comment: Your newest edit makes sense to me, but I tried it and get this error: `Error: Invalid value { col: 'actionData' }`. (According to the types `sequelize.where` won't accept a simple string as the first argument.) I'm on the latest, Sequelize 6.17.0, if that matters.

Comment: What is "actionData" ? Is it a column of the same table ? A column from a joint table ? When there are joints between tables Sequelize may rename the columns to `'Tablename.fieldname'` instead of `'fieldname'`. So maybe try adding the table name before the field name.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. I have simplified the table structure for this question and missed a change in my comment. The correct error is `Error: Invalid value { col: 'data' }`. `sequelize.col('data')` appears to be generating an object, which `sequelize.where` doesn't know what to do with.